# Congestion control behaviour of TCP Reno

Tags: tcp, congestion

Which behaviour of TCP Reno after 3 DUP ACK is correct:

- The one described in the Italian Wikipedia (https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Controllo_della_congestione_in_TCP#TCP_Reno). It says the new cwnd is: cwnd_new = cwnd_old/2 + 3*MSS
- The one described in the English Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP_congestion_control#TCP_Tahoe_and_Reno). It says the new cwnd is: cwnd_new = cwnd_old/2

I guess, it's the Italian Wikipedia that is right, since also the FSM in the book "Computer Networking: A Top-Down Approach, Kurose & Ross" shows it like that (http://www.linyibin.cn/images/Technology-ComputerNetworking-Internet-TCP-CongestionControl.png).

Is there a (good) reason why many sources neglect the term "+3*MSS"?

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question does not keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

When TCP Reno sender gets 3 duplicate ACKs, it enters a so called fast retransmit mode. The idea of this mode is that a) since ACKs are delivered it indicates that packets are leaving the network b) if a packet leaves a network, the sender can inject new packet in the network. Duplicate ACK indicates that a packet has left the network. Fast retransmit increases congestion window for each duplicate ACK received. This is called "inflating". The 3 MSS (3 segments) are added upon entering, because 3 duplicate ACKs were already received. Now, this increase persists only in fast retransmit. When the mode is exited, congestion window is set to sstresh (which is cwnd_old/2, i.e., congestion window before the first duplicate ACK is received/2).

So, on 3 dupacks the sender does:

- set sstresh = cwnd/2
- set cwnd = sstresh
- enter fast recovery (upon entering **increase cwnd by 3 segments to account for already received dupacks** cwnd=cwnd + 3 MSS)
- in fast recovery increase cwnd by 1 segment on each duplicate ack
- when first non-duplicate ack is received exit fast recovery; set cwnd = sstresh **(without 3 extra segments!)**

So, technically these two sources described the state at 2 different points in time.

(fast retransmit specification here: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5681#section-3.2)

Answer (score 0):

From *Computer Networking A Top-Down Approach* 6th Edition by Kurose & Ross linked to in English Wikipedia:

> The congestion window then climbs linearly until a triple duplicate-
> ACK event occurs, just after transmission round 8. Note that the
> congestion window is  12  •  MSS when  this  loss  event  occurs.  The
> value  of  ssthresh is  then  set  to 0.5 • cwnd = 6 • MSS. **Under
> TCP Reno, the congestion window is set to cwnd = 6 • MSS** and then
> grows linearly. Under TCP Tahoe, the congestion window is set to 1 MSS
> and grows exponentially until it reaches the value of ssthresh, at
> which point it grows linearly.

Potentially, *cwnd_new = cwnd_old / 2 + 3 * MSS* is counter-productive for a very small window when the value actually grows.